# Swap two number from string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have a string that contains two numbers and some text. I want to swap the two numbers with each other, ex. "22-33" will be "33-22" in a second string. Is that possible?

The string will be with different numbers, but only with two digts each and they will stay at the same place in the string.

Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure just split them first like this:

```
NSString *myString = @"22-33";
    NSArray *strings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString  *reversedNumbers = [[[strings lastObject] stringByAppendingString:@"-"] stringByAppendingString:[strings objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", [components objectAtIndex:1], [components objectAtIndex:0]];
```